# firestore using transaction twice in same function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I`m curious if there is no disadvantage when I use transaction method inside transaction method on Android.

like this

```
db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Double>() {
@Override
public Double apply(Transaction transaction) throws 
FirebaseFirestoreException {
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(sfDocRef);
    double newPopulation = snapshot.getDouble("population") + 1;
    if (newPopulation <= 1000000) {

    db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Double>() {
             ....
    }

    } else {
        throw new FirebaseFirestoreException("Population too high",
                FirebaseFirestoreException.Code.ABORTED);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advise against this.  Transactions can be retried if there is a collision with another client also performing a transaction with any of the same documents.  You should expect that the transaction body could run more than once.  This means your inner transaction could be performed more than once, which is almost certainly not going to have the effect you want.  There could be other side effects that are unwanted.  For example, what do you think will happen if the inner transaction is trying transact with any of the same documents as the outer transaction?

Comment: thank you what about just get()method inside get()method or set()method inside set()method?

Comment: If you're not modifying the document, I would do that before the transaction and make the data available to the transaction, immutable.  Transactions should complete as fast as possible, should not maintain any sort of state, and should not block on external data.

Comment: Sorry, I meant what if it is not transaction method and it`s just twicing set or get method? then there is no problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Maybe you should post a new question and explain what the issue is?